# Dragging a element at a position of Cursor in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am trying to build a game in React, It needs a Drag-and-drop feature. The game has two major components, SideBar and a GameBoard. SideBar contains elements to be dragged onto GameBoard. The Drag and Drop works, but the element is getting dropped at the incorrect position (Offset from the position of the cursor), I looked for resources online on how to drop at the position of cursor but most of the answers are only using a third party package and the ones that are not do not really have an answer

You can see the output of the below code here: https://gist.github.com/assets/31410839/48cbdaae-2323-461e-a660-286d0fc971bd

Here is complete code

App.tsx which holds the SideBar and GameBoard with draggedElement state

```
// App.tsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import GameBoard from "../src/components/GameBoard/GameBoard";
import SideBar from "../src/components/SideBar/SideBar";
import { ElementData } from "./Types";
function App() {
  const [draggedElement, setDraggedElement] = useState<ElementData | null>(null);
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col md:flex-row bg-gray-100">
      <div className="md:w-1/5 bg-fuchsia-50 p-4">
        <h1 className="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Infinite Things ♾️</h1>
        <SideBar setDraggedElement={setDraggedElement} />
      </div>
      <div className="md:w-4/5 bg-amber-50 flex-grow">
        <GameBoard draggedElement={draggedElement} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

GameBoard.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Element from "../Element";
import { ElementData } from "../../Types";

interface GameBoardProps {
  draggedElement: ElementData | null;
}

const GameBoard: React.FC<GameBoardProps> = ({ draggedElement }) => {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState<ElementData[]>([
    { id: "Water", dx: 0, dy: 0, color: "#3498db" },
    { id: "Fire", dx: 0, dy: 0, color: "#e74c3c" },
    { id: "Wind", dx: 0, dy: 0, color: "#2ecc71" },
  ]);

  const [draggingElement, setDraggingElement] = useState<ElementData | null>(null);

  const handleDrop = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.currentTarget.style.border = "none";

    if (draggedElement) {
      // Check if the dropped element is from the sidebar or internal drag
      const isExternalDrop = !draggingElement;  // Corrected this line

      if (isExternalDrop) {
        // External drop: add the dragged element from the sidebar
        const rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
        const y = e.clientY - rect.top;

        const newElement = { ...draggedElement, dx: x, dy: y };
        setElements((prevElements) => [...prevElements, newElement]);
      } else {
        // Internal drop: update the position of the dragged element
        const rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
        const y = e.clientY - rect.top;

        const updatedElement = { ...draggingElement, dx: x, dy: y };

        setElements((prevElements) =>
          prevElements.map((el) => (el.id === draggingElement.id ? updatedElement : el))
        );
      }
    }

    // Reset the dragging element in the state
    setDraggingElement(null);
  };


  const handleDragStart = (
    e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>,
    element: ElementData
  ) => {
    console.log("drag start", element.id);
    // Set the dragged element in the state
    setDraggingElement(element);

    // Set data to be transferred during the drag
    e.dataTransfer.setData("elementId", element.id.toString());
  };

  const handleDragOver = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Check if there's a dragging element
    if (draggingElement) {
      // Calculate new position based on cursor location
      const rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
      const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
      const y = e.clientY - rect.top;

      // Update dx and dy in draggingElement (or state)
      setDraggingElement((prevElement) => {
        if (prevElement) {
          return { ...prevElement, dx: x, dy: y };
        }
        return prevElement;
      });
    }
  };


  const handleDragEnd = () => {
    // Reset the dragging element in the state
    setDraggingElement(null);
  };

  const handleDragEnter = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.currentTarget.style.border = "2px dashed #333";

    // Get the elementId from dataTransfer only if draggingElement is null
    if (!draggingElement && draggedElement) {
      console.log("drag enter", draggedElement?.id);
      setDraggingElement(draggedElement);
    }
  };

  const handleDragLeave = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    e.currentTarget.style.border = "none";
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="game-board bg-gray-200 relative h-full p-4"
      onDrop={handleDrop}
      onDragOver={handleDragOver}
      onDragEnter={handleDragEnter}
      onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
      onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
    >
      <h2 className="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Game Board</h2>
      <div className="min-w-0 absolute">
        {elements.map((element) => (
          <Element
            key={element.id}
            element={element}
            onDragStart={(e) => {
              e.dataTransfer.setData("elementId", element.id.toString());
              handleDragStart(e, element);
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GameBoard;
```

Sidebar which holds the elements

```
// SideBar.tsx
import React from "react";
import Element from "../Element";
import { ElementData } from "../../Types";

interface SideBarProps {
  setDraggedElement: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<ElementData | null>>;
}

const SideBar: React.FC<SideBarProps> = ({ setDraggedElement }) => {
  const elements: ElementData[] = [
    { id: "Water", dx: 0, dy: 0, color: "#3498db" },
    { id: "Fire", dx: 0, dy: 0, color: "#e74c3c" },
    { id: "Wind", dx: 0, dy: 0, color: "#2ecc71" },
  ];

  const handleDragStart = (
    e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>,
    element: ElementData
  ) => {
    console.log("drag start in Sidebar for", element.id);
    setDraggedElement(element);
  };

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <h2 className="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Side Bar</h2>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
        {elements.map((element) => (
          <Element
            key={element.id}
            element={element}
            onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, element)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SideBar;
```

Element component which will be dragged

```
// Element.tsx
import React from "react";
import { ElementData } from "../Types";
interface ElementProps {
  element: ElementData;
  onDragStart: (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>, element: ElementData) => void;
}

function Element({ onDragStart, element }: ElementProps) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`element p-4 min-w-4 text-white text-center font-bold rounded-2xl shadow-lg cursor-pointer`}
      onDragStart={(e) => {
        onDragStart(e, element);
      }}
      style={{
        background: `${element.color}`,
        transform: `translate(${element.dx}px, ${element.dy}px)`,
      }}
      draggable
    >
      {element.id}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Element;
```

Apologies if the code looks messy, I am a beginner in React.

Answer (score 1):

In `handleDrop()` in `GameBoard`, you need to fully account for the starting position of the element being repositioned. This is because `translate()` moves the element relative to its "starting" position.

```js
// Get the cursor position, relative to the top-left corner of the `.game-board` element.
const rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
const y = e.clientY - rect.top;

// Get reference to the element of the inner `<div class="min-w-0 absolute">`
// the contains the draggables.
const inner = e.currentTarget.children[1];

// Find the index of the draggable we dropped.
const i = elements.findIndex(el => el.id === draggingElement.id);
// Get the DOM element of the draggable inside the game board.
const domElement = inner.children[i];
        
const updatedElement = {
  ...draggingElement,
  // Offset `dx` and `dy` values so they are relative to the "starting" position of the draggable.
 dx: x - inner.offsetLeft - domElement.offsetLeft - domElement.offsetWidth/2,
 dy: y - inner.offsetTop - domElement.offsetTop - domElement.offsetHeight/2,
};
```

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;

function Element({ onDragStart, element }) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`element p-4 min-w-4 text-white text-center font-bold rounded-2xl shadow-lg cursor-pointer`}
      onDragStart={(e) => {
        onDragStart(e, element);
      }}
      style={{
        background: `${element.color}`,
        transform: `translate(${element.dx}px, ${element.dy}px)`,
      }}
      draggable
    >
      {element.id}
    </div>
  );
}

const GameBoard = ({ draggedElement }) => {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([
    { id: "Water", dx: 0, dy: 0, color: "#3498db" },
    { id: "Fire", dx: 0, dy: 0, color: "#e74c3c" },
    { id: "Wind", dx: 0, dy: 0, color: "#2ecc71" },
  ]);

  const [draggingElement, setDraggingElement] = useState(null);

  const handleDrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.currentTarget.style.border = "none";

    if (draggedElement) {
      // Check if the dropped element is from the sidebar or internal drag
      const isExternalDrop = !draggingElement;  // Corrected this line

      if (isExternalDrop) {
        // External drop: add the dragged element from the sidebar
        const rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
        const y = e.clientY - rect.top;

        const newElement = { ...draggedElement, dx: x, dy: y };
        setElements((prevElements) => [...prevElements, newElement]);
      } else {
        const rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
        const y = e.clientY - rect.top;
        
        const inner = e.currentTarget.children[1];
        
        const i = elements.findIndex(el => el.id === draggingElement.id);
        const domElement = inner.children[i];
        
        const updatedElement = {
          ...draggingElement,
          dx: x - inner.offsetLeft - domElement.offsetLeft - domElement.offsetWidth/2,
          dy: y - inner.offsetTop - domElement.offsetTop - domElement.offsetHeight/2,
        };
        setElements((prevElements) => {
          return prevElements.map((el) => (el.id === draggingElement.id ? updatedElement : el))
        });
      }
    }

    // Reset the dragging element in the state
    setDraggingElement(null);
  };


  const handleDragStart = (
    e,
    element
  ) => {
    console.log("drag start", element.id);
    // Set the dragged element in the state
    setDraggingElement(element);

    // Set data to be transferred during the drag
    e.dataTransfer.setData("elementId", element.id.toString());
  };

  const handleDragOver = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Check if there's a dragging element
    if (draggingElement) {
      // Calculate new position based on cursor location
      const rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
      const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
      const y = e.clientY - rect.top;

      // Update dx and dy in draggingElement (or state)
      setDraggingElement((prevElement) => {
        if (prevElement) {
          return { ...prevElement, dx: x, dy: y };
        }
        return prevElement;
      });
    }
  };

  const handleDragEnd = () => {
    // Reset the dragging element in the state
    setDraggingElement(null);
  };

  const handleDragEnter = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.currentTarget.style.border = "2px dashed #333";

    // Get the elementId from dataTransfer only if draggingElement is null
    if (!draggingElement && draggedElement) {
      console.log("drag enter", draggedElement.id);
      setDraggingElement(draggedElement);
    }
  };

  const handleDragLeave = (e) => {
    e.currentTarget.style.border = "none";
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="game-board bg-gray-200 relative h-full p-4"
      onDrop={handleDrop}
      onDragOver={handleDragOver}
      onDragEnter={handleDragEnter}
      onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
      onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
    >
      <h2 className="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Game Board</h2>
      <div className="min-w-0 absolute">
        {elements.map((element) => (
          <Element
            key={element.id}
            element={element}
            onDragStart={(e) => {
              e.dataTransfer.setData("elementId", element.id.toString());
              handleDragStart(e, element);
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const SideBar = ({ setDraggedElement }) => {
  const elements = [
    { id: "Water", dx: 0, dy: 0, color: "#3498db" },
    { id: "Fire", dx: 0, dy: 0, color: "#e74c3c" },
    { id: "Wind", dx: 0, dy: 0, color: "#2ecc71" },
  ];

  const handleDragStart = (
    e,
    element
  ) => {
    console.log("drag start in Sidebar for", element.id);
    setDraggedElement(element);
  };

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <h2 className="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Side Bar</h2>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
        {elements.map((element) => (
          <Element
            key={element.id}
            element={element}
            onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, element)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [draggedElement, setDraggedElement] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col md:flex-row bg-gray-100">
      <div className="md:w-1/5 bg-fuchsia-50 p-4">
        <h1 className="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Infinite Things ♾️</h1>
        <SideBar setDraggedElement={setDraggedElement} />
      </div>
      <div className="md:w-4/5 bg-amber-50 flex-grow">
        <GameBoard draggedElement={draggedElement} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked like a charm, I have made minor edits to also offset the  dimension of the element being dragged